# MudBlazor select dropdown is opening in the top of the page

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I'm somewhat new to web development and Blazor/MudBlazor. I'm encountering an issue with MudBlazor's select component's dropdown menu, opening in the top of the page. I've tried moving the component to different pages, but I encounter the same issue each time.

Are there any tips or advice on what I can do here to troubleshoot this issue so that the dropdown opens in the correct location?

[image]

(Edit 1 - 12/09/2023):
It appears that this issue occurs when `<MudThemeProvider>` is present.
Code that replicates the issue is available here: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QEGnOXPvzKSLNYNB

Comment: You need to show the code you have, just enough to reproduce the problem. Better if you create a working (with your problem) snippet here https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet

Comment: Hello @RBee. I've put the code on try.mudblazor.com that seems to replicate the issue: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QEGnOXPvzKSLNYNB

Comment: After identifying what was causing the issue, it looks like this problem has already been reported with a GH issue created: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/4777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [issue](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/4777) you've linked is definitely the right issue for this behaviour however, it is not an issue that is going to be addressed, as the underlying cause of the issue is the incorrect usage of the components.

The popover for all the components are provided by the `MudPopoverProvider` which is a service that is inside the `MudThemeProvider` component.

You need to have the `MudThemeProvider` instantiated **separate** from all the other components as described in [their docs](https://mudblazor.com/getting-started/layouts#basic-layout).

```html
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<MudThemeProvider @bind-IsDarkMode="@_isDarkMode" Theme="_theme" />

<MudContainer Class="d-flex justify-end">
    <MudSwitch @bind-Checked="_isDarkMode" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ma-4" T="bool">Toggle Light/Dark Mode</MudSwitch>
</MudContainer>
<MudGrid Class="cursor-default justify-center align-center">
    <MudItem>
        <MudSelect T="double" Label="Price" Variant="Variant.Outlined" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter">
            <MudSelectItem T="double" Value="4.50" />
            <MudSelectItem T="double" Value="4.99" />
            <MudSelectItem T="double" Value="3.60" />
        </MudSelect>
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
```

---

And the [MudBlazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QEGnOXPvzKSLNYNB) is not working because the REPL environment itself is also a component which is already inside the `MudMainContent` component. Essentially:-

```html
<MudThemeProvider/> <!-- Instantiated here-->
<MudDialogProvider/>
<MudSnackbarProvider/>

<MudLayout>
    <MudMainContent>
        @Body
        <MudThemeProvider/> <!-- Created again -->
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>
```

If you check the browser dev console you will see this error.

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: Duplicate MudPopoverProvider detected. Please ensure there is only one provider, or disable this warning with PopoverOptions.ThrowOnDuplicateProvider.
System.InvalidOperationException: Duplicate MudPopoverProvider detected. Please ensure there is only one provider, or disable this warning with PopoverOptions.ThrowOnDuplicateProvider.
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I had <MudThemeProvider/> in two locations in my project. That was indeed the issue! I'll see about trying to access the MudThemeProvider via a cascading parameter or something.

Comment: Np! yep, that is the way.